# Cancan with database roles and abilities: AuthorizationNotPerformed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authorization, cancan

I'm building a [site-wide](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Ensure-Authorization) cancan auth system. Just to get very simple validation of my attempts, I'm initializing my test cases every time I try to hit a page:

```
# application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  admin = Role.new(name: :admin, is_default: true)
  admin.permissions << Permission.create(action: :manage, subject_class: :all)
  admin.save
  current_user=User.create!
  # users automatically get associations to all roles with `is_default: true`

  check_authorization
end
```

Only controllers with `skip_authorization_check` are letting me through, all others throw the [`AuthorizationNotPerformed`](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/blob/master/lib/cancan/controller_additions.rb#L251) error:

```
CanCan::AuthorizationNotPerformed in ExampleAuthEngin::PermissionsController#index

This action failed the check_authorization because it does not authorize_resource. Add skip_authorization_check to bypass this check.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the controller, you need to either call `load_and_authorize_resource` (at the class level), or within individual actions call `authorize! :action, resource` where `:action` and `resource` are the things to be tested. load_and_authorize_resource adds before_filters to the controller that instantiates an instance variable for the resource (where the method of instantiation is based on the action, and the resource to load is based on the controller name) and also adds a filter to authorize the loaded resource, authorizing on either :read, :create, :update, or :destroy, based on the action that's being hit.

You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Controller-Authorization-Example).

Comment: Well that helps a lot. Just based on the [wording of the `check_authorization` method documentation](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/#4-lock-it-down) I thought that `load_and_authorize_resource` was assumed for all models without `skip_authorization_check`. Now my models attributes and routes are working, and I can work on the (currently quite broken) model methods and controller logic. Thanks!

Comment: No Prob. :) Very cool that you're putting it in an engine. That's something my team has thought of doing ourselves. I'm sure there would be strong demand for it if you open sourced.

Comment: I've got the bare bones running sufficiently for my current project. There are many more projects I'll be building with it, so once it reaches that undefinable level of sophistication where one is proud enough to open source code, I'll track this post down and point you to it. :)

Comment: Aside from generators with configuration options, the other main feature I want to add before public release is an improved [Database-stored Abilities](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Abilities-in-Database) hack that allows for more advanced user-defined permissions to take full advantage of cancan's flexibility.

Comment: In my todo list are 1) allow permission negation (`cannot`), 2) allow Role-less special cases on a per-user basis, 3) allow an advanced permissions option with a few commonly-used block-level Ability patterns (namely `if user owns object` and `if object has state open/closed/etc`, definable in a .yml.) If you have any open-sourced code yourself your team has build, I'd love a pointer to it to get started!

Comment: Great, I'd definitely like to know when you do release. We haven't open sourced anything related to authorization, though there is another rails developer in the Charlotte area (where I'm located) that open sourced an alternative to CanCan called "Authority". But it doesn't provide persistence options and also doesn't provide an engine. One thing I think would be a nice add on to database backed abilities, if you're shopping for feature requests, would be the option to cache permissions, so the database doesn't have to be hit on every request.

Comment: I've just had this same issue, solved by putting what I thought was a redundant load_and_authorize_resource into my failing controllers, that work ok out of tests. So this appears to be a "bug" with cancan, or incomplete documentation?